# Create filename with a counter in a command

Tags: macros, naming

the code below is not efficient as I would like :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{nomfigcpt} % compteur pour compter les figures insérées dans le document
\newcommand{\nomfig}{\jobname\_fig\_\thenomfigcpt.pdf\stepcounter{nomfigcpt}}

\begin{document}

\nomfig

\nomfig

%\includegraphics[scale=1]{\nomfig}

\end{document}
```

As you can see on the pdf the command

> \nomfig

is efficient but when I want to use it in

> \includegraphics

it doesn't work instead of the file is in the directory.

I suppose that my solution is too naive and I have tried to find a solution without any success.

I use pdflatex -synctex=0 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Is anyone could help me ?

Comment: `\stepcounter` is not expandable, which means you can't use it in a file name. You will have to split the `\stepcounter{nomfigcpt}` part of the command and the file name. Also the `\_` need to be only `_` in the file name.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{nomfigcpt}
\newcommand{\nomfig}{\jobname\_fig\_\number\value{nomfigcpt}.pdf\stepcounter{nomfigcpt}}
\newcommand{\curfig}{\jobname_fig_\number\value{nomfigcpt}.pdf}

\begin{document}

\nomfig

\nomfig

\includegraphics[scale=1]{\curfig}

\end{document}`

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik : Thank you. I have understood the idea. I think that Schrödinger's cat has given the solution.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat : thanks a lot for the solution. Unfortunately, the second command [code]\curfig[\code] does not increment the counter. Is there any way to do both get the name as a string and incremet the counter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mandatory argument to `\includegraphics` must expand to a string of characters, in order to identify a file name. Instructions such as `\stepcounter{...}` cannot be used in that argument.

A simple way out is to use a new command:

```latex
\newcommand{\numberedimage}[1][]{%
  \includegraphics[#1]{\jobname_fig_\arabic{nomfigcpt}}%
  \stepcounter{nomfigcpt}%
}
```

so you can call either form:

```latex
\numberedimage

\numberedimage[width=\textwidth]
```

Comment: This is the perfect and final solution to my problem. Thank you very much.